# Homebrew - How to Enable php 5.5

Tags: php, localhost, homebrew

I have installed latest php 5.5.5 and I have no clues how to run it.
Currently I can see integrated php 5.4.17 or so from OS X Mavericks.

I was wondering what should I type in apache file, since none of those from screenshot do not work, except default integrated one by uncommenting first line.

[image: 1st HTTPD.CONF Preview]

[image: 2nd Terminal Preview]

So, can someone please tell me what is the path for newest php that I have installed ? If I type `php -v` in terminal it will show version 5.5.5 but not on `localhost/~dvLden`

Answer (score 2):

All you need to type is

```
$> which php
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Note I have a later version of PHP 5.5, which I installed via Homebrew.

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.9/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```